# printf of float value outputs error 'invalid number'

Tags: bash, printf

The script has follow an output:

```
#!/bin/bash

h=12
m=8
s=34.2342345463
printf "%02d:%02d:%06.3f\n" $h $m $s
```

output:

```
line 10: printf: 34.2342345463: invalid number
12:08:34,000
```

Comment: Please try: `LC_NUMERIC=C printf ...`

Comment: Cannot reproduce on mint 19, without LC_NUMERIC set in my environment.